# how to save a Thunderbird message in an extansion

Tags: save, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am trying to write an addon for Thunderbird that saves time saving Messages from Thunderbird, by creating the Filename out of Date, Subject, etc. of the mail.
After quite a bit of digging around i found the Command cmd_saveAsFile and the function MsgSaveAsFile(), which both got me a lot closer to what i want to do. The Problem is: i can't find anywhere if those to function accept Parameters, and if they do: which kind of parameters.

If anybody here can help me, or point me in the direction of a decent, (more or less) up to date documentation for Thunderbird i would be very thankfull (because so far, i didn't find anything really usefull).

Thanks a lot,
Zoldor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how:

```
messenger.saveMessages(gFolderDisplay.selectedMessages.length, stringArray, msgArray);
```